# Eval() Error with eval()'d error

Tags: php

YES. I searched google for any answers.

I am learning php. I am trying to send email using some php code that has this eval line.

```
eval("job();");
```

But getting error:

> eval()'d code on line 1

Any advice?

Comment: Does `function job () {}` exist?

Comment: Is the function `job()` defined?

Comment: `<?php
eval ('test();');

function test () {
    echo 'test';
}` works for me

Comment: If you're learning PHP, don't learn bad habits like using eval()

Comment: eval = "evil" ;) the warning is in the function name

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `eval()`. [It's evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php).

Assuming `job` is a [function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php), you can call `job()` directly.

```
job();
```

If `job()` returns a value, you can assign it to use later, as needed.

```
$variable = job();
```

Answer (score 0):

Either call the function directly (if you know the name - judging by your snippet, you do) *or*, if you don't know what function needs to be called (it depends on a variable value or something, try using [call_user_func](http://www.php.net/call_user_func) or similar functions.
Also make sure the function exists with [function_exists](http://www.php.net/function_exists), for example

There's a whole bunch of functions, built into PHP that allows you *not* to use eval... just spend some time browsing through the docs